# Selecting and filtering on the same variables in dplyr

Tags: r, subset, dplyr

Let's say we have a matrix with 3 columns and a 100 rows. Let the column names be `a_dem`, `b_dem` and `c_blah`. And let's  imagine that each cell can have a value between 0 and 100.

Is there a way to use `select()`, `filter()` and `%>%` to select only the observations that end with "_dem" and have a value larger than, say, 50?

I would've kinda imagined that it would be along these lines:

```
dat %>% 
    select(ends_with("dem")) %>%
        filter(>50) %>%
            summary()
```

but that doesn't work, obviously.

So, is there a way to do this kind of selection and filtering, or would I have to resort to something more complicated?

Comment: Best thing that I know of is to use `gather()` and `spread()` from `tidyr` to turn your "dem" variables into values, and filter just one column.

Comment: the cells only have numeric values, so essentially you want to just select the first two columns?

Comment: @sgp667 I'll look into that, thanks!


LloydChristmas :The idea is to select the first two columns and take only the observations that have a value greater than 50 in both of those columns.

Comment: Something like `dat[dat$a > 50 & dat$b > 50, c("a", "b")]` or `dat[dat$a > 50 & dat$b > 50, 1:2]` or `dat[dat$a > 50 & dat$b > 50,][c("a", "b")]` will work in base R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(2)

a_dem <- runif(100,0,100)
b_dem <- runif(100,0,100)
c_blah <- runif(100,0,100)

dat <- data.frame(a_dem, b_dem, c_blah)

newdat1 <- dat %>%
select(ends_with("_dem"))

filtered <- sapply(newdat1, function(x) ifelse(x>50, x, NA))

>head(filtered)

        a_dem    b_dem
[1,]       NA       NA
[2,] 70.23740       NA
[3,] 57.33263 98.06000
[4,]       NA 82.89221
[5,] 94.38393       NA
[6,] 94.34750 59.59169
```

And then depending on what you want to do next you could easily just exclude the `NA` values.

---

Update:

To do this completely in `dplyr` you can use the method that was linked to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39613767/how-to-use-anonymous-functions-for-mutate-each-and-summarise-each) by @sgp667

```
newdat2 <- dat %>%
   select(ends_with("_dem")) %>%
   mutate_each(funs(((function(x){ifelse(x>50, x, NA)})(.))))

> head(newdat2)
     a_dem    b_dem
1       NA       NA
2 70.23740       NA
3 57.33263 98.06000
4       NA 82.89221
5 94.38393       NA
6 94.34750 59.59169
```

Comment: Hey, I tried using this concept on a dataset I'm working on and it seems to work, thanks :) 

I was actually just trying to find a way to do it with %>% and without creating temp variables. But this works, and it's not too long, so it's cool :)

Comment: I added how to do it completely in `dplyr` using the %>% command.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of another way:

```
dat %>%
  mutate_each(funs(over=(function(x)x>2)(.)),ends_with("dem")) %>% 
  mutate(all_true=all(ends_with("over"))) %>%
  filter(all_true == TRUE) %>%
  select(ends_with("dem"))
```

This might be very verbose but you can filter through an arbitrary number of columns.

I found our [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39613767/how-to-use-anonymous-functions-for-mutate-each-and-summarise-each) how you can use a custom formula in `mutate_each`.

The way this works is mutate_each applies `funs()` to all columns that match `ends_with("dem")` criteria, and function applied here is `(function(x)x>2)(.)` which is an anonymous function(it is exactly what it sounds like just a function that I didn't bother naming). 
Syntax for anonymous functions is:

`(function(some parameters) some instructions)(values for parameters)`

In this case function returns TRUE if `x` is greater than `2`, and value passed as `x` is `.`(and `.` is `dat`, the reason why this works is because of pipe `%>%` ).

1. So the `mutate_each` line produces additional columns, new columns have "over" at the end of their name.
2. Next line creates another column(called `all_true`) that also has TRUE/FALSE value which is TRUE if `all` columns that `end_with("over")`have TRUE.
3. `filter` simply removes rows which have FALSE in `all_true` column.
4. Lastly `select` includes just the columns that match `ends_with("dem")`

Comment: Hey, could you elaborate on this a bit, please? I tried using the concept on a dataset I'm currently working on, but I can't make it transfer. 

What does this piece do: 

     mutate_each(funs(over=((function(x)x>2))(.)),ends_with("dem"))

And why is there a (.)?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! 

I tried to use the code to filter out the "Unknown" and "Adult" values from an age variable, but haven't been able to make it work. 

I tried adding (x!=<==>"Adult" |<&> x!=<==>"Unknown") to the anonymous function call, and tried making the function: function(x) ifelse((x=="Adult" | x=="Unknown"), NA, x)), but these approaches haven't worked. 

The code between <> denotes the alternatives I have tried.

Comment: @Potato can you try `!x %in% c("Adult,"Unknown")`. FYI this tests in values is in vectro t othe right of `%in%` and the `!` in front reverses value of the test.

Comment: That didn't do it either :/

Answer (score 0):

I though of another `tidyverse` solution:

```
dat %>%
select(ends_with("_dem")) %>%
  map_df(function(x) ifelse(x > 50, x, NA))
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to install the tidyverse package, so I wasn't able to test the code. But still, thanks for the suggestion and thanks for revealing the tidyverse package to me :)